# esnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

Tags: python, keras, arguments, resnet

I have this error in my code:

> esnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5', errno = 22,
>   error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

I try to run a binary classification here.

Please, let me know how you are fixing it if you had the same error.

Thanks

```
NUM_CLASSES = 2
CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_RESIZE = 224
RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE = 'avg'
DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION = 'softmax'
OBJECTIVE_FUNCTION = 'binary_crossentropy'
LOSS_METRICS = ['accuracy']
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE = 3
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING = 10
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION = 10
BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING = 100
BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION = 100
BATCH_SIZE_TESTING = 1
WEIGHTS_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET\\resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5"
model = Sequential()
train_data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET"
from keras.models import load_model

model = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights='imagenet') 
x = model.output  
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)
model.summary()
print(model.summary())
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9), metrics= ['binary_accuracy'])
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET"
batch_size = 32
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_size = IMAGE_RESIZE
def append_ext(fn):
return fn+".jpg"
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
train_dir_path = dir_path + '\data'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path, f))]
NUM_CLASSES = 2
data_labels = [0, 1]
t = []
maxi = 25145
LieOffset = 15799
i = 0
while i < maxi: # t = tuple
    if i <= LieOffset:
    t.append(label['Lie'])
else:
    t.append(label['Truth'])
i = i+1
train_datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2) # set validation split 20% versus 80% pour training ### Aka ivghigh 

train_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='binary', shuffle=False, subset='training') # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, # same directory as training data kifkif
    target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
    class_mode='binary', shuffle=False, subset='validation') # set as validation data
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET \\resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')

fit_history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING,
    epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION,
    callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper]
    )

model.load_weights('..\resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')
```

Thanks for your help and regards

Comment: Your error message is incomplete, you should include the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, this is the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Desktop/RESNET/ResNet50VF9.py', wdir='C:/Users/h.mokrane/Desktop  /RESNET')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
    file "C:/Users/Desktop/RESNET/ResNet50VF9.py", line 412, in 
    model.load_weights('../resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1152, in load_weights
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 269, in __init__
fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 99, in make_fid
fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)

File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

file "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open

OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '../resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No   such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```